# How to get duration from wav file if it is read as regular binary file?

Tags: python

I know there is `wave.open`. However, I need to get wav duration if variable already has wav file content, as if I opened it as regular binary file, such as:

```
    with open('file.wav', 'rb') as wav_file:
        wav_data = wav_file.read()
```

so how do I get wav file duration out of `wav_data` variable?

Comment: Can you use `BytesIO` to send the already-read `wav_data` into `wave.open`?

Comment: yep. `BytesIO` did the job. Thanks @Noleli

Comment: Also, `len_data = len(wav_data)  duration = len_data / samplerate` works but `BytesIO` of course a better way

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. `len_data/samplerate` also won’t account for header or other metadata in the raw wav.